# First part of the proof of "The Jouanolou trick"

Tags: linear-algebra, algebraic-geometry

Let me state the Jouanolou trick first: (throughout the field is $k$, which is algebraically closed)

For any projective variety $X$, there is an affine variety $Y$ and an onto map $Y\to X$ such the fibers of this map are isomorphic to an affine space, $\mathbb{A}^N$.

Actually the proof of the above proposition is pretty simple once we prove the following:

Denote by $Y$ the set of idempotent $n\times n$ matrices $M^2=M$ (i.e. $M\in \mathrm{Mat}_n(k)$), such that $\mathrm{rank}(M)=1$. Then $Y$ is an affine variety (closed subvariety of $M\in \mathrm{Mat}_n(k)\equiv \mathbb{A}^{n^2}$).

First of all $M^2=M$ gives $n^2$ polynomial equations restricting the matrices to only idempotent ones. So it only remains to impose the $\mathrm{rank}(M)=1$ condition. This is basically where I got stuck:

> How to implement $\mathrm{rank}(M)=1$ on a matrix using only polynomial equations?

**1st Attempt**:  I argued (at first) that $\mathrm{rank}(M)=1$ means that the characteristic polynomial is $x^{n-1}(x-1)$, so it should be enough to demand $M^{n-1}(M-1)=0$ by Cayley-Hamilton. But this is nothing new since if $\mathrm{rank}(M)\neq 0, n$ and $M^2=M$, then in general $M^{m}(M-1)^{n-m}=M(M-1)$.

**2nd Attempt**: I demanded $\det (1-M)=0$ and $\det M=0$, this restricts rank of $M$ to $0<\mathrm{rank}(M)<n$. But this isn't going anywhere either.

**3rd Attempt**: Suppose $M$ is of rank one. Construct a $2\times n$ matrix $N(i,j)$ having the $i$th row of $M$ as its first row and the $j$th row of $M$ as its second row. Now $\mathrm{rank}(N(i,j))$ is either zero or one. Meaning the rows of $N(i,j)$ are linearly dependent. So we have a polynomial relating these rows together. Doing it for all the pairs of rows imposes rank one condition completely. But then I realized, these polynomials are heavily dependent on the specific form of $M$, so again they are no good either.

Any hints about how to implement $\mathrm{rank}(M)=1$ on a matrix using a polynomial equation?

Comment: Rank $1$ means that the determinant of every $2\times2$ minor evaluates to $0$ (and that the matrix is not the zero matrix). This can be expressed using $n^2(n-1)^2/4$ polynomial equations (and then remove the origin).

Comment: Great! Thank you... Exactly what I needed.

Comment: Dear @Arthur,  there is something fishy going on: if you remove a point (here the zero matrix) from an affine variety of dimension $\geq 2$ then the  remaining variety will no longer be affine!

Comment: Dear hamedp, you should indeed require that the characteristic polynomial  be  $x^{n-1}(x-1)$. This **implies** but is **not equivalent** to $M^{n-1}(M-I)=0$: think of the zero matrix whose characteristic polynomial is $x^n$

Comment: The fishy point is now cleared: the algebraic set  given by $M^2=M$ and $\operatorname {rank} ( M) \leq 1$ is **not connected** and has $O$ as an isolated point. So you may remove $O$ and, bizarrely, still get an affine algebraic set (which might now  be irreducible, but I'm not sure).

Comment: Dear @GeorgesElencwajg, actually you don't need to remove zero, you just need to make sure it is not a solution to your system of equations. One can do that by $\det (1-M) = 0$ which is always true for our matrices of interest. So basically I ended up demanding $M^2=M$, zero determinants for minors and $\det (1-M) = 0$ as the generators of ideals corresponding to this affine variety.

Comment: For your second remark, I'm aware of your point. But $x^{n-1}(x-1)$ is a polynomial is third party indeterminents and not of coordinates of matrices (it won't give a variety in $Mat_n(k)$. So you need a way to force this characteristic polynomial onto the coordinates of your matrices. My question was basically how to do that. Minors do this job perfectly.

Comment: Dear hamedp: About  your first comment: well, yes but you have removed zero by asking $det (I-M)=0$ .About your second comment: the matrices with characteristic polynomial equal to $x^{n-1} (x-1)$ form an algebraic affine subset  $Y \subset \mathrm{Mat}_n(k)$ which is **exactly** the affine subset  you want. There is no need for minors at all if you adopt this point of view. And please modify  the assertion  in your "1st attempt" claiming that "it is enough to demand that $M^{n-1}(M-1)=0$".  It is not enough: look at  nilpotent matrices with $M^2=O\neq M$.

Comment: I know my first attempt is nonsense, just wanted to explain my train of thought. So is this true "The set of polynomials having the same characteristic polynomial is an affine variety"? I didn't know that. How can one prove it? Maybe it is obvious and I'm just stupid...

Comment: Nevermind of course it is obvious. I'm just confusing myself. Thank you.

Comment: Dear @hamedp: no, you are definitely not stupid! The characteristic polynomial of $M$ is $x^n-tr(M)x^{n-1}+...+p_i(M)x^i+...+(-1)^n det(M)$. The point is that $p_i$ is a polynomial in the  $n^2$ entries  $m_{ij}$ of $M$. The expression for the polynomial $p_i(M)$ is  rather complicated, but you can find it in [this entry of Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_polynomial#Properties).

Comment: Beautiful! Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Here is a beautiful geometric illustration of Jouanoulou's trick, suggested by a friend of mine, in the simplest case where $X=\mathbb P^1$.

The rank $1$ projections $M=M^2: k^2\to k^2$ correspond **exactly** to **distinct ordered pairs** $(K,I)$ of one dimensional vector subspaces $K,I\subset k^2$.
The bijective correspondence is simply given by $\operatorname {Ker}(M)=K$ and $\operatorname {Im}(M)=I$.
But these pairs form  the variety $Y=\mathbb P^1\times\mathbb P^1\setminus \Delta $, where $\Delta \subset \mathbb P^1\times\mathbb P^1$ is the set of pairs $(L,L)$ consisting of twice the same line $L\subset k^2$.
This set $Y$ is affine. Here is why:

The Segre map $$\mathbb P^1\times\mathbb P^1\to \mathbb P^3: ([x_0,x_1],[y_0,y_1])\mapsto [z_0=x_0y_0,z_1=x_0y_1,z_2=x_1y_0,z_3=x_1y_1]$$ (whose image is the smooth quadric $z_0z_3-z_1z_2=0$) sends $Y$ **isomorphically** onto the **closed** subset $Y' =V(z_0z_3-z_1z_2)\cap U\subset U$ of the open subset $U=\mathbb P^3\setminus V(z_1-z_2)$ .
 But this open set $U$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb A^3$ (since it is the complement of a hyperplane in $\mathbb P^3$) and thus $Y'\subset U$ is affine.

**Conclusion:** The variety $Y$ (which is isomorphic to $Y'$) is affine, isomorphic to a closed smooth quadric surface in $\mathbb A^3.$

**Edit:**  I forgot to say that the morphism $f:Y\to X=\mathbb P^1=\mathbb P(k^2)$   is given by $(K,L)\mapsto K$ .
The fiber $f^{-1}(K)$ consists of all the pairs $(K,L)$ with $L\neq K\subset k^2$ and is thus a closed subset  $f^{-1}(K)\subset Y$ isomorphic to $\mathbb A^1$.
Hence we obtain a locally trivial bundle $f:Y\to X=\mathbb P^1$ with total space an affine variety and  with fiber $\mathbb A^1$, 
but which   cannot be made into  a vector bundle because it has no section.
   [Because the image of that section would be a projective line embedded in the affine variety $Y$ : utter nonsense !].
Quite interesting this Jouanolou trick, isn't it?